# Set source image of image control

Tags: vb.net, image, windows-phone-8.1

I programming for Windows Phone 8.1. I use this way to create image and set source of image:

```
Dim AgreeBitmapImage As BitmapImage = New BitmapImage()
AgreeBitmapImage.setsource(New Uri("Assets/Image/Agree.png", UriKind.Relative))
//Above line gives an error
imgAccept = New Image
imgAccept.Height = 40
imgAccept.Width = 40
imgAccept.Source = AgreeBitmapImage
```

When I start the emulator, it doesn't work. Why? (Say error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows Phone 8.1, the resources like png should be get using `ms-appx`:

```
AgreeBitmapImage.UriSource = 
    New Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Image/Agree.png", UriKind.Absolute)
```

Comment: You should use UriSource instead of setSource method